# OS X on Hyper-V in Windows 8

Tags: mac-osx, hyper-v

Is there any earthly way to get OS X to run in Hyper-V (the distro that comes with Windows 8 Pro)?

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: No way that is officially supported by Apple, nor to my knowledge can this be done without violating the OS X EULA. I encourage you to contact Apple if you're really interested in trying this though.

Comment: It wouldn't be against the EULA if Windows is running on Apple hardware. The problem is that Microsoft does not offer OS X/Darwin as a guest OS option. However, it shouldn't be too hard for MS to fix this if there was a will—personally I'd love to see this done—by implementing support for presenting the SMC hardware to the VM, the presence of which is a prerequisite for OS X booting, just like VMWare did. For comparison, see: http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2011/08/when-can-i-run-apple-osx-on-vsphere-5.html

Answer (score 2):

No. The only *official* way to run OSX in a virtual machine is to install ESXi onto an official Mac server. Then Darwin will show up as a guest option, and then you can install.

I say this as someone who has lost many hours in attempting to do this, EULA violation or not (in the end we just bought the damn Mac Mini server. Cheaper, easier, no fuss).